# Routing multiple gets for WebApi in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, routes

I'm creating a rest API in ASP.NET MVC4, and am having a problem with routing. For reference, I've already read these questions but they haven't answered my problem:

- [Web API Routing - api/{controller}/{action}/{id} "dysfunctions" api/{controller}/{id}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596391/web-api-routing-api-controller-action-id-dysfunctions-api-controller)
- [Web Api Routing for multiple Get methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775590/web-api-routing-for-multiple-get-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4)
- [Routing in Asp.net Mvc 4 and Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775887/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-web-api)

The urls I'm looking to craft can be as follows:

1. GET /account/id (where id is a Guid) - equivalent to GET /account/?id=x
2. GET /account/first%20last%20name (where name is a
   string) - equivalent to GET /account/?name=x
3. GET /pendingregistrations/?page=y (here the action is omitted)
4. POST /pendingregistrations/denyregistration?denyId=x (here an action is specified)

As you can see, in some cases the URL after the controller name maps to a parameter (id and name in #1,2 above), and sometimes the action name (#4 above). In addition, it may be not present at all (#3 above), in which case I assume a default action. Here is the routing that is working for almost all cases:

```
    // Match for an id next.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "WithIdApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index" },
        constraints: new
        {
            id = @"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$"
        }
    );

    // Match for a name next.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "WithNameApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{name}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index" }
    );

    // Match for an action last.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "WithActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index" }
    );
```

This code works for everything except example #4 above, because MVC can't tell the difference between a 'name' parameter, and an 'action' binding. If I change the order (i.e. put the match for action above), then the 'name' parameter example will never work.

Does anyone know of any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for anyone else trying to do this, the answer is it isn't possible. Best thing to do is to move the 'name' search into it's own action. For example:

- GET /account/id (where id is Guid)
- GET /account/name/first%20last

I would have assumed MVC would have attempted to match parameters, or actions, if one or the other failed and other bindings were available, but sadly this is not the case.