# Web API routing: how to convey "api/{controller}/latest" as well as "api/{controller}/{id}"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This question is pretty close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596391/web-api-routing-api-controller-action-id-dysfunctions-api-controller), with a minor twist.

I would like to set up a Web API routing table so I can make a request like `api/items/5` as well as `api/items/newest` so the client can get the newest item.

I've been paging through [some articles](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) but haven't had much luck in determining whether I'm going about it the right way.

My first question is, what's the "right" or "clean" way to allow a caller to find the newest `item`?  Is it OK to do something like `api/items/newest` or is that frowned upon?

Currently, this seems to work in my WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "NewestItems",
    routeTemplate: "api/items/newest",
    defaults: new { controller = "Items" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ItemsById",
    routeTemplate: "api/items/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Items" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This approach works, but I'm curious if there's a more generic way to do this without making a controller-specific routing rule.  I had tried the following approach, but it didn't work since the rules were ambiguous:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionWithNoArgument",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Is there a more effective way to do this without resorting to controller-specific routing rules?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "NewestItems",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/newest",
    defaults: new { controller = "Items" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ItemsById",
    routeTemplate: "api/items/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Items" }
);
```

routes are processed top down, and putting `{controller}` makes it generic for any controller

Comment: +1 for explaining that routes are processed top down.