# Setting up custom API route

Tags: c#, asp.net

Working in ASP.NET 4.6 here.

I have a controller:

```
public class ComputerController : ApiController
{
    ...

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/computer/ping")]
    public IHttpActionResult Ping(int id)
    {
        return Ok("hello");
    }

    ...
}
```

Going mostly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596391/web-api-routing-api-controller-action-id-dysfunctions-api-controller) (look at MSTdev's answer), I have this in my `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
// So I can use [Route]?
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
// handle the defaults.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The route doesn't work. I always get

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
'http://localhost:29365/api/computer/ping'.
```

This seems like such a simple problem, yet I remain stumped. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route is missing the {id} parameter. 
Ex.

```
[Route("api/category/{categoryId}")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetCategoryId(int categoryId) { ... }
```

Your controller should look like this:

```
public class ComputerController : ApiController
{
    ...

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/computer/ping/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Ping(int id)
    {
        return Ok("hello");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Sure enough. Thank you.