# Why does the default http route does not contain {action}

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

Why does the default Web Api 2 http routing not contains `{action}`:

From the microsoft sample:

```
// Configure Web API for self-host. 
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Why does it not look like this:

```
// Configure Web API for self-host. 
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Why is the action part not required for correct routing?

The code is rom http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because in that mode the methods are matched by Http Verbs (Get , POST, PUT) and by parameters. You can add `{action}` and then that would match by the method name.

Answer (score 1):

The actions in the example are matched implicitly.  If you look, they are all different HTTP verbs.

Comment: Ok, so adding `{action}` would not cause any problems? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I were you, I would use [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) instead.  It's more explicit.  I have never had to change the default route.

Comment: Thank you for that hint!

Comment: If you want a specific answer to your question, this question is very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596391/web-api-routing-api-controller-action-id-dysfunctions-api-controller